# ActiveMQ Topic messages are getting stuck, resent in bulk after glitch

Tags: kubernetes, activemq-classic, amq

**Environment:**

- ActiveMQ deployed on kubernetes
- Producer Java Application using openwire
- Subscribers Python and C client using MQTT

**Problem Statement:**

- Producer is sending message after every seconds on Topic and subscriber receiving it accordingly.
- But sometime once or thrice a day subscriber stop receiving messages for around 4 to 8 seconds then client receive all missing messages within 1 second in bulk.
- I have enabled debug logs in ActiveMQ but couldn't find any exception/error or warn

Following are client side logs

```
2020-08-26 07:13:18,852 - DEBUG - Received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0), 'App/status'
2020-08-26 07:13:19,765 - DEBUG - Received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0), 'App/status'
2020-08-26 07:13:20,829 - DEBUG - Received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0), 'App/status'
2020-08-26 07:13:21,784 - DEBUG - Received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0), 'App/status'
**Here its 5 seconds gap**
2020-08-26 07:13:26,831 - DEBUG - Received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0), 'App/status'
2020-08-26 07:13:28,745 - DEBUG - Received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0), 'App/status'
2020-08-26 07:13:29,905 - DEBUG - Received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0), 'App/status'
2020-08-26 07:13:30,917 - DEBUG - Received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0), 'App/status'
2020-08-26 07:13:31,484 - DEBUG - Received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0), 'App/status'
**Three seconds Gap**
2020-08-26 07:13:34,221 - DEBUG - Received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0), 'App/status'
2020-08-26 07:13:34,881 - DEBUG - Received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0), 'App/status'
2020-08-26 07:13:37,450 - DEBUG - Received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0), 'App/status'
2020-08-26 07:13:38,078 - DEBUG - Received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0), 'App/status'
**Below Can be seen all missing messages received within 1 seconds**
2020-08-26 07:13:40,391 - DEBUG - Received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0), 'App/status'
2020-08-26 07:13:40,422 - DEBUG - Received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0), 'App/status'
2020-08-26 07:13:40,423 - DEBUG - Received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0), 'App/status'
2020-08-26 07:13:40,423 - DEBUG - Received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0), 'App/status'
2020-08-26 07:13:40,423 - DEBUG - Received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0), 'App/status'
2020-08-26 07:13:40,423 - DEBUG - Received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0), 'App/status'
2020-08-26 07:13:40,423 - DEBUG - Received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0), 'App/status'
2020-08-26 07:13:40,456 - DEBUG - Received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0), 'App/status'
2020-08-26 07:13:40,456 - DEBUG - Received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0), 'App/status'
2020-08-26 07:13:40,962 - DEBUG - Received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0), 'App/status'
2020-08-26 07:13:43,400 - DEBUG - Received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0), 'App/status'
2020-08-26 07:13:43,475 - DEBUG - Received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0), 'App/status'
2020-08-26 07:13:44,431 - DEBUG - Received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0), 'App/status'
2020-08-26 07:13:45,139 - DEBUG - Received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0), 'App/status'
2020-08-26 07:13:46,074 - DEBUG - Received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0), 'App/status'
2020-08-26 07:13:46,787 - DEBUG - Received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0), 'App/status'
```

Although there is no loss of messages but my application need update within seconds and strange is this happen twice or thrice in 24 hours and random time.

**Update1:**
After doing lot of optimizations and refactoring i finally found root cause

***Publisher to Broker Tracs:***
[image]

Publisher suppose to send Frequency status after every 12 millisec but from 13:28:08.132 till 13:28:08.174 it didn't send status and then send all previous missing in one message.

***Broker to client logs***
In below logs we can see clients received status at 175th, 176th, 176th, 177th, 181ist milliseconds. Client was sensitive about it and expect message after every 12 millisec rather than all in one shot

```
2020-09-27 13:28:08,120 - DEBUG - Received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0), 'PKGCTRL/1/status/frequency', ...  (49 bytes)
2020-09-27 13:28:08,134 - DEBUG - Received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0), 'PKGCTRL/1/status/frequency', ...  (49 bytes)
2020-09-27 13:28:08,175 - DEBUG - Received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0), 'PKGCTRL/1/status/frequency', ...  (49 bytes)
2020-09-27 13:28:08,176 - DEBUG - Received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0), 'PKGCTRL/1/status/frequency', ...  (49 bytes)
2020-09-27 13:28:08,176 - DEBUG - Received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0), 'PKGCTRL/1/status/frequency', ...  (49 bytes)
2020-09-27 13:28:08,177 - DEBUG - Received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0), 'PKGCTRL/1/status/frequency', ...  (49 bytes)
2020-09-27 13:28:08,181 - DEBUG - Received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0), 'PKGCTRL/1/status/frequency', ...  (49 bytes)
2020-09-27 13:28:08,188 - DEBUG - Received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0), 'PKGCTRL/1/status/frequency', ...  (49 bytes)
2020-09-27 13:28:08,200 - DEBUG - Received PUBLISH (d0, q0, r0, m0), 'PKGCTRL/1/status/frequency', ...  (49 bytes)
```

Comment: Have you enabled GC logging to correlate the pauses in message delivery with what the JVM is doing at the time?

Comment: @JustinBertram Thanks for asking, I have enabled GC logs and monitoring, But it look like more issue related to network, my broker and client are on different network switch so we are using routing between them, recently we remove routing and connect both at layer 2 level(switching), Things are much better now, But its still under observation and will update accordingly.

Comment: @JustinBertram I updated my question with new updates.